# Hotly contested

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, cryptic-clues, geography

> 1. Arab dad infiltrating computer network islands (6)
> 2. Franco-German brown egg is peaceful abode (6)
> 3. Haiku song corrupted southern port (9)
> 4. No heartless Swedes in springtime capital basin (9)
> 5. Darling headless ape, haven with pleasant scent (8)
> 6. Sodian fish view body of water (9)
> 7. Southern isle hiding alpha in a northern (6)
> 8. Trachtenberg and colleague Lee make central metropolis (6)
> 9. UFO mails GF chaotically large bay (10)
> 10. Uranium as backwater resort place (5)

Where are we?

Hint:

> The Swedes have an affinity for melody.

Comment: Good stuff. Shouldn't 4 be (6, 3) rather than (9)? Gave all the solvers a bit of a problem, I think.

Comment: @RupertMorrish It appears you're right. I haven't been using separate numbers at all even when the answer is multiple words. Need to start doing that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arab dad infiltrating computer network islands (6)

> Arab Dad is ABU, Computer Network is LAN; gives LABUAN, an island in Malaysia (L + ABU + AN).

Franco-German brown egg is peaceful abode (6)

> Thanks to @hexomino for this one: French for brown is BRUN, German for egg is EI. BRUN + EI = the Sultanate of BRUNEI.

Haiku song corrupted southern port (9)

> Haiku song rearranged gives the southern port of KAOHSIUNG, Taiwan.

No heartless Swedes in springtime capital basin (9)

> I think the Swedes as alluded to in the hint are ABBA; heartless might mean ABA. No means NIL. A springtime month is MAY. Putting it together yields NIL ABA in MAY => MA + NIL ABA + Y => MANILA BAY, a capital basin off the coast of the Philippines in the South China Sea!Thanks very much to @M Oehm, who discovered the final answer and parsing of the clue!

Darling headless ape, haven with pleasant scent (8)

> @M Oehm is currently on a really nice roll here: finding that Darling = HON, the Headless Ape is KING KONG - KIN. The Haven is therefore HONG KONG, which translates to fragrant harbour.

Sodian fish view body of water (9)

> Sodian = NA, the fish is TUNA, and view = SEA. Then the body of water is NATUNA SEA, an offshoot of the South China Sea. Thanks to @M Oehm for finding this!

Southern isle hiding alpha in a northern (6)

> alpHA IN A Northern hides the southern Chinese isle of HAINAN.

Trachtenberg and colleague Lee make central metropolis (6)

> Not Michelle but DAN Trachtenberg, and not Michelle but ANG Lee make the central metropolis of DA NANG, Vietnam. Thanks to @M Oehm for finding this!

UFO mails GF chaotically large bay (10)

> UFO mails GF rearranged gives GULF OF SIAM, a large bay in Thailand

Uranium as backwater resort place (5)

> uranIUM AS backwards spells SAMUI, an island in Thailand

Looks like we're in

> Southeast Asia this time! Per @WAF, we might be more specifically in the (hotly contested) South China Sea! Thanks, @WAF!

Comment: Perhaps we are in the rot13(ubgyl pbagrfgrq Fbhgu Puvan Frn)?

Comment: Good going, I managed to figure out the second one as being rot13(oeharv)

Comment: WAF seems to have a point. I have found the sodian fish {AN + GHAN + FRN } and Trachtenberg {QNA + NAT}.

Comment: I think the darling is {UBA(rl) + (xva)T XBAT, zrnaf "sentenag uneobhe"}. As for the Swedes in springtime, there's [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yinggehai_basin), which fits the description, but I have absolutely no idea how to parse it, which probably means that it's wrong.

Comment: @M Oehm maybe heartless Swedes - Ivxvatf, sebz juvpu lbh fbzrubj trg Lvat?

Comment: @Gnudiff: Great explanation! However, I believe that usually in cryptic clues, a word like heartless is used to clue some modification to another clue word itself (in this case, removing the middle of another word) rather than as a descriptor for another word.

Comment: https://bit.ly/2DzldNt lists 14 basins in the area, and only  rot13(Lvattrunv) has 9 letters.

Comment: @RupertMorrish that’s a second vote for M Oehm’s basin suggestion — I’m definitely appreciating the additional backup, but I still have no clue how to parse that word into the cryptic clue...

Comment: Okay, it's rot13(ZNAVYN ONL = AVY NO(o)N va ZNL). It was clear who the Swedes were from the hint, but I didn't think of the second word that El-Guest proposed in the edit. So the "capital" is part of the defiition. rot13(V tbg n ybg bs uvgf sbe FVATNCBER ONFVA, ohg nyy bs gurz jrer sbe onguebbz svkgherf.)

Comment: @MOehm I _knew_ it had to be that but was completely stumped on the passing again. Well done on putting it all together!! :D

Comment: Nice teamwork, guys! All correct now!